# Dock sometimes doesn't let me click

Tags: macbook-pro, dock, big-sur

I run macOS Big Sur on a MacBook Pro 2015 (refurbished). Sometimes, I'll click on an icon on the dock and it won't respond, but I can right click on the icon to open a new window. This is very frustrating. I've tried the command `sudo killall dock` in Terminal (zsh) and it worked briefly, but the problem persists at random times. It's not so vital but it is annoying and I don't know how to fix it. Could I have some help on how to make a permanent fix (hopefully without anything messy or big)?

Comment: Does this happen with other macs running macOS Big Sur? If you downgrade, does this still happens?

Comment: I have not thought about downgrading... and I don't have any other Macs.

Comment: Can you install a brand new system on an external hard drive, boot from that, and see if you encountered the same problems?

Comment: Or try booting in Safe Mode?

Comment: Had you tried Diagnostics (press d on startup)?